# Android SQLiteException no such table

Tags: android, sqlite

friends.

I try to use a pre-created custom database in my android app. First I copy my DB using this code.

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {



    final String DB_DESTINATION = "/data/data/com.example.android.sqlitedatabaseexample/databases/turkish2.db";


            boolean initialiseDatabase = (new File(DB_DESTINATION)).exists();
            if (initialiseDatabase == false) {


                // Open the .db file in your assets directory
                InputStream is = null;
                try {

                    is = context.getAssets().open("turkish2.db");


                // Copy the database into the destination
                OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(DB_DESTINATION);
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int length;
                while ((length = is.read(buffer)) > 0){
                    os.write(buffer, 0, length);
                }
                os.flush();

                os.close();
                is.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
```

then I check if database exists calling this method

```
 public boolean checkDataBase() {
            /*Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "работаю", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();*/
            SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
            try {
                checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase("/data/data/com.example.android.sqlitedatabaseexapple/databases/turkish2.db", null,
                        SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS/*OPEN_READONLY*/);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "БД на месте", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                checkDB.close();
            } catch (SQLiteException e) {
                // database doesn't exist yet.
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "БД не существует", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            return checkDB != null;
        }
```

...it shows that my database exists! Then I try to make query but get an exception.

My database contains two tables - android_metadata and turkish. BUT.
While I check all tables using this

```
Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table'", null);

                if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                    while ( !c.isAfterLast() ) {
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Table Name=> "+c.getString(0), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        c.moveToNext();
                    }
                    Toast.makeText(this, "DATS ALL SUKA", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
```

It showl like I have only android_metadata table. Alse when I try to make query to the table I need (turkish table) it shows SQLiteException: no such table 'turkish'

What am I doing wrong? Help please.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Consider using [sqlite-asset-helper](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper)

Comment: Now it works! Thank you so much, friend, u saved my life!